# In JavaScript ES6, isn't the iterator next(value) received by yield processed afterwards?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Here is a simplified version of the [example in Mozilla of resetting a generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators):

```js
function* oddNumberGenerator() {
  let i = 1;
  while (true) {
    reset = yield i;
    i = reset ? 1 : i + 2;
  }
}

const oddNumberIterator = oddNumberGenerator();

console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 1
console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 3
console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 5

console.log(oddNumberIterator.next(true)); // 1

console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 3
console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 5
```

It seems the `true` passed in would be assigned to `reset`, but the `yield` already should have yield a `7` already.  Why does it yield `1` -- what is the order of execution that makes it not return `7` but `1`?

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(oddNumberIterator.next()); // 5
```

Once this line completes, the generator is paused on the right hand side of the yield statement, with `i` equal to 5. It's currently waiting instructions to know what to assign to `reset`

```
console.log(oddNumberIterator.next(true)); // 1
```

By calling next and passing in true, you tell the generator to resume, with the result of the **previous** yield being `true`. So reset gets set to true, and the generator keeps running, setting `i` to 1, looping, and then yielding that 1. The value of 1 (along with done: false) is returned, and gets passed to console.log.

Comment: I thought when it yield the first 5, the yield 5 has already finished running and there already is a value assigned to `reset`, which is `undefined`... if seems we are saying, the `yield 5` didn't return a value yet... the `next(true)` afterwards actually give that return value, seemingly for the previous `yield`? That seems strange

Comment: That's correct. The generator evaluates the right hand side of `reset = yield i;` first. The yield causes it to pause. It can't finish the assignment until you call next again.

Comment: if an analogy is made, let's call that particular yield operation as "Peter". it is like "the father got the yielded value from Peter, but the son provides the return value of Peter"

Comment: I think of generators as a two way conversation. The generator uses yield to say "here's what i've got so far. What do you want me to work on next?" and on the iterator side uses `.next` to say "thanks for the information, here's what you should do next".

Answer (score 1):

The value given to `yield` is the result of `next`, and the value given to `next` is the result of `yield`. They do not have to be the same.